# Installing MySQL 5.6 using PPA

Tags: 12.04, ppa, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL 5.6 on my Ubuntu 12.04 over the already installed 5.5 the easy way (using `PPA`s).

I've found Ondřej Surý's PPA [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/mysql-5.6). It sounds promising but I couldn't upgrade my MySQL. Here are the steps I've taken:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu precise main'`
2. Openning `Update Manager` I pressed `Check` button to retrieve the database for newly added repository.
3. A bunch of packages were listed including MySQL client 5.6 and others but they were all small packages (matter of kB).
4. I downloaded and installed all of the listed packages (except one which I'll tell you about it later).
5. Restarted `mysqld` daemon.

Having done all above, I see no change in my MySQL server version, it's still 5.5.35! The one package that didn't install was perhaps the most important one, it's called:

```
MySQL database sever (metapackage depending on the latest version)
mysql-server (Size: 88 kB)
```

And the reason why I didn't install it is because I can't! Even though it's there in my update manager's list with a check-box but the check-box is disabled and I'm unable to check it. It's just stuck there and won't go away or anything.

Did I miss a step or something? How can I install MySQL 5.6?

Comment: On the small chance you haven't seen this yet: http://askubuntu.com/questions/203330/how-to-install-mysql-5-6?newreg=3bcb2395659b4aa0b674517bbe3d8e48 Hope it helps.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just run the following commands:

```
apt-get -y remove mysql-server
apt-get -y autoremove
apt-get -y install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
apt-get update
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Comment: I didn't remove mysql, just add repo, update and install mysql and its work Thanks :)

Comment: At time of writing this, it appears that ondrej's repository is inactive - these commands result in 404 errors on `update` - [see his comment here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/433014/unable-to-install-mysql-5-6-in-ubuntu-12-04#comment1055434_433015)

Comment: This worked for me today.

Comment: At time of writing this, Ondrej's MySQL repositories say not to use as they are broken.