# Unable to install mysql 5.6 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mysql

I download mysql-5.6.16-debian6.0-x86_64.deb from official site.
Install using `dpkg -i mysql-5.6.16-debian6.0-x86_64.deb`
It does create file in `/opt/mysql/server-5.6/`.

```
root@ubuntu:~# cd /var/lib/mysql/
bash: cd: /var/lib/mysql/: No such file or directory
root@ubuntu:~$ service mysql start
mysql: unrecognized service
root@ubuntu:~$ chown -R mysql /opt/mysql/server-5.6/
chown: invalid user: mysql
root@ubuntu:~$ chgrp -R mysql /opt/mysql/server-5.6/
chgrp: invalid group: mysql
```

I don't know how to deal with this...

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l /opt/mysql/server-5.6/
total 152
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 17987 Jan 14 23:38 COPYING
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 docs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 include
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 88109 Jan 14 23:38 INSTALL-BINARY
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 lib
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Mar 11 16:32 man
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 mysql-test
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  2496 Jan 14 23:38 README
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 scripts
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 share
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 sql-bench
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar 12 11:56 support-files
```

Comment: try `sudo service mysql start`

Comment: @Avinash Raj root user, mysql: unrecognized service

Comment: post the contents of `ls -l /opt/mysql/server-5.6/`

Comment: @Avinash Raj I have updated the question.

Comment: How did you get `-bash: cd: /var/lib/mysql/: No such file or directory` this error.

Comment: @Avinash just `cd: /var/lib/mysql/`, because it should be a `mysql` dir in `/var/lib/`, isn't it?

Comment: @Avinash I'm in.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to do that:

easily you can install mysql:

server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

client only

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

---

If you want newer versions than default in Ubuntu

for version 5.5;

```
sudo  apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.5
```

for version 5.6;

```
sudo  apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
```

After adding your needed version, update sources lis:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

now install mysql

server:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

client only

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

Comment: Because 12.04 defaut install mysql 5.5.

Comment: so you need specific version?

Comment: yes, I just want to use the newest.

Comment: ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6 doesn't support Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) anymore, see the notice I just wrote here: https://deb.sury.org/ubuntu-precise-and-PHP-5.4-eol.html

Comment: `sudo apt-add-repository -y 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-experimental/ubuntu precise main'`

Answer (score 1):

According to the official [MySql Site](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/) for community Server Installation, you can follow the guide described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/).

This guide helps you configure an apt repository for MySQL products according to your OS Version and MySQL Product (server, connectors) version. In brief for Ubuntu 12.04 and MySQL Server 5.6 you follow the step below.

1. Download the APT package, in our case `mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1ubuntu12.04_all.deb`
2. Run it using `# dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.3.5-1ubuntu12.04_all.deb`
3. Update APT source list `# apt-get update`
4. Install as usual `# apt-get install mysql-server`

Comment: Please update your answer. I tried following it and there are some additional steps necessary in order to install this mysql-apt-config .deb file since this answer was posted on September 3, 2015.

Answer (score 0):

If you install mysql server from .deb file, it stores the service file inside `/etc/init.d` directory as `mysql.server`.So to start the mysql server service, you have to run the below command,

```
sudo service mysql.server start
```

To initialize mysql Data directory, see [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-install-db.html) documentation page.

Comment: Why there is a downvote for this answer,plz explain me.

Comment: Me and op discussed about this problem on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company)

Answer (score 0):

`ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6` stopped working a few days ago for me on CircleCI for some reason (the tests suddenly broke and Circle didn't change anything). I'm now upgrading MySQL 5.5 -> 5.6 [based on instructions here](http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/updating-mysql-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-to-mysql-5-6-2015-04-02/). It uses the official MySQL apt.

```
echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ precise mysql-apt-config" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
echo "deb http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu/ precise mysql-5.6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysql.list
curl -s http://ronaldbradford.com/mysql/mysql.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo service mysql stop
sudo apt-get install -y mysql-server
sudo mysql_upgrade -uroot # -p omitted as the circleci default container has no password
```

Comment: ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6 doesn't support Ubuntu Precise now, see the notice I just wrote here: https://deb.sury.org/ubuntu-precise-and-PHP-5.4-eol.html