# Mysql installation problems ubuntu Precise

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install mysql-server package, but I have this error message:

```
/home/nikitasorokin# apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaio1 ndn-mysql5-helper
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) ...151108 11:54:25 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
151108 11:54:25 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) starting as process 14876 ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Apt-cache

```
/home/nikitasorokin# apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5
mysql-server-5.5:
  Installed: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Candidate: 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 0
        500 http://mirror.newdream.net/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirror.newdream.net/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 5.5.22-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://mirror.newdream.net/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5`

Comment: Try running 'mysqld' from command line and check staking and /var/log/mysql/... files for any error messages

Comment: `root@ps481138:/home/nikitasorokin# mysqld
151108 16:09:50 [Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
151108 16:09:50 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) starting as process 6750 ...` and then nothing...

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/454416/462484)'s a step by step procedure to install mysql in Ubuntu 12.04. The repository is given in question by OP. Here's how to add that repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.6/ubuntu precise main'
```

The question is marked solved so I assume It's a successful solution.

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work for me. I have persisted error, which I've marked before

Comment: @7_R3X Don't link other questions as your answer, click `flag` under the question and flag it as a duplicate, so it goes to the review queue.

Comment: At my opinion it is not a dublicate: my problem is quite different

Comment: @NikitaSorokine I am not saying it is, just saying this answer is just copied from another one on the site and that is discourage, just because one user flags a question does not mean it is a duplicate, five users with enough rep must all agree. Anyway I am making an answer

Answer (score 0):

Start by taking a step backwards and purge whatever partial install the system is finding.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server
```

Follow that with an attempt to get rid of any busted config files.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Now you're starting fresh.  You shouldn't have to add the repository.  Just try

```
sudo apt-get install msyql-server
```

In fact, I'm pretty sure that MySql server and client are both available through the Software Center as far back as Precise.