# Is it possible to install MySQL 5.5 or 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package-management, mysql, 16.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04. Unfortunately I need to work MySQL 5.5 or 5.6. I tried many solutions to have MySQL 5.5 or 5.6 run on Ubuntu 16.04 like this [Install MySql 5.6 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762384/install-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-16-04) .
But none of them is working.
Ubuntu detect the unmet dependencies but says "but it is not going to be installed" for 5.5 or says Package 'mysql-server-5.6' has no installation candidate...

Is it not possible to force an earlier version of MySQL on Ubuntu? Why is that?

Comment: The official Ubuntu 16.04 repositories do not contain any version of MySQL other than 5.7. If you want another version, you have to find package from another source. You should really not have upgraded to 16.04 without checking this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install MySQL 5.6?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203330/how-to-install-mysql-5-6)

Comment: Which of the answer(s) of the linked question did you try? Some use the Deb package from Oracle or even compile it from source which should work no matter the state of the software repository.

Comment: @fkraiem "You should really have no upgraded ... without checking this" - you're presuming the necessity of MySQL 5.5 was known at the time of upgrading. I recently started a new job with old software which requires MySQL 5.5 (nothing newer) - so I should have checked all possible employers and what they are running before upgrading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/258598/116889)  helped me figure out how to do it by downloading the `.deb` packages from MySQL dev site. The solution about adding the PPA did not do it for me.

It links to a blogpost: [How to Install MySQL-5-6 on Ubuntu Precise](http://www.peterchen.net/2013/02/20/en-how-to-install-mysql-5-6-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise/)
Tricky but it works.

Answer (score 25):

Step by step guide* to install mysql 5.5.x on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial-Xerus. Please see this [documentation](https://www.scribd.com/document/320972085/Install-MySQL-5-5-Ubuntu16-04-Xenial-Xerus)

OR

See steps below:

Installing MySQL 5.5.51 on Ubuntu 16.06

1. Uninstall any existing version of MySQL

   ```
   sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/ -R
   ```
2. Delete the MySQL profile

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/mysql/ -R
   ```
3. Automatically uninstall mysql

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove mysql* --purge
   sudo apt-get remove apparmor
   ```
4. Download  version 5.5.51 from MySQL site

   ```
   wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.56-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
5. Add `mysql` user group

   ```
   sudo groupadd mysql
   ```
6. Add `mysql` (not the current user) to `mysql` user group

   ```
   sudo useradd -g  mysql mysql
   ```
7. Extract `mysql-5.5.51-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz` to `/usr/local`

   ```
   cd /usr/local
   sudo tar -xvf mysql-5.5.49-linux2.6-x86_64.tar.gz
   ```
8. Create `mysql` folder in `/usr/local`

   ```
   sudo mv mysql-5.5.49-linux2.6-x86_64 mysql
   ```
9. Set `mysql` directory owner and user group

   ```
   cd mysql
   sudo chown -R mysql:mysql *
   ```
10. Install the required lib package

    ```
    sudo apt-get install libaio1
    ```
11. Execute mysql installation script

    ```
    sudo scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
    ```
12. Set mysql directory owner from outside the mysql directory

    ```
    sudo chown -R root .
    ```
13. Set data directory owner from inside mysql directory

    ```
    sudo chown -R mysql data
    ```
14. Copy the mysql configuration file

    ```
    sudo cp support-files/my-medium.cnf /etc/my.cnf
    ```
15. Start mysql

    ```
    sudo bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql &
    sudo cp support-files/mysql.server /etc/init.d/mysql.server
    ```
16. Initialize root user password

    ```
    sudo bin/mysqladmin -u root password '111111'
    ```
17. Start mysql server

    ```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server start
    ```
18. Stop mysql server

    ```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server stop
    ```
19. Check status of mysql

    ```
    sudo /etc/init.d/mysql.server status
    ```
20. Enable myql on startup

    ```
    sudo update-rc.d -f mysql.server defaults
    ```
21. Disable mysql on startup (Optional)

    ```
    sudo update-rc.d -f mysql.server remove
    ```
22. Add mysql path to the system

    ```
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql /usr/local/bin/mysql
    ```
23. Now directly use the command below to start mysql

    ```
    mysql -u root -p
    ```

PS: One needs to reboot in order for the changes to take place.

Based on a Chinese [blog](http://quangelab.com/ubuntu-mysql/)

Comment: Works like a sharm! Thank you. Only one thing - if you install MySQL on Ubuntu 16 - do not create systemctl script - after rebooting it will create by itself automatically.

Comment: The reboot needs to occur between steps #16 and #17 for steps #17-21 to work.

Comment: did all this but ended up with dependency problems (presumably some shared libraries got into a wrong version).

Comment: Is it really necessary to remove `apparmor`? I'm not seeing a line to reinstall afterwards. I don't know too about apparmor but it seems like uninstalling it is a security issue.

Comment: Still work without removing apparmor

Comment: Works perfectly: thank you.

Remember to restart the MySQL server after the stop/status commands

Comment: What's happening in 12?

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you ! +1

Comment: This works. The instructions on Oracle's website don't....

Answer (score 4):

Try this,
First you have to remove

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mysql/debian-5.7.flag
```

then

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe'
```

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt install mysql-server-5.6
```

```
sudo apt install mysql-client-5.6
```

Answer (score 2):

A simpler alternative is to use Percona Server. By their [documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/installation/apt_repo.html#installing-percona-server-from-percona-apt-repository):

## Installing Percona Server from Percona apt repository

1. Fetch the repository packages from Percona web:

   ```
   wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_0.1-4.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
   ```
2. Install the downloaded package with **dpkg**. To do that, run the following commands as root or with **sudo**:

   ```
   dpkg -i percona-release_0.1-4.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb
   ```

   Once you install this package the Percona repositories should be added. You can check the repository setup in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/percona-release.list` file.
3. Remember to update the local cache:

   ```
   apt-get update
   ```
4. After that you can install the server package:

   ```
   apt-get install percona-server-server-5.5
   ```

Comment: HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found

Comment: @simhumileco they changed the version. as of today, use wget https://repo.percona.com/apt/percona-release_0.1-4.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb and then dpkg -i percona-release_0.1-4.$(lsb_release -sc)_all.deb